# CSS misc alignment and formatting issues with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I'd like my DIV to the left (in light grey) to be split into 2 parts: `col-md-3` which would contain a big map pin icon, and `col-md-9` which would contain the address (and a little arrow overlapping the next box).

Unfortunately what I have tried does not return the expected results. The increased font size class is not taken into consideration for the map pin (from font awesome) and same goes for the address-specific classes.

What is the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/un4tp74p/

**What I'd like to achieve:**

[image]

**What I get:**

[image]

```
<div class="container offset-60px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes white-smoke">
                <div class="col-md-3 green">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker map-pin"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <p class="top-address-name">Company name</p>
                    <p class="top-address-street">address line 1</p>
                    <p class="top-address-street">address line 2</p>
                    <p class="top-address-tel">Tel number</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes apple">
                <p>John Doe</p><span>Born in Japan</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 intro-boxes chateau-green">
                <p>Jane Doe</p><span>Born in France</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--- END container -->
```

CSS:

```
.map-pin {
font-size: 58px;

}


.top-address-name {
font-size: 18px;
color: #4A4A4A;
}

.top-address-street {
font-size: 18px;
color: #37A187;
}

.top-address-tel {
font-size: 14px;
color: #4A4A4A;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/un4tp74p/2/) 
1- If you want to add nested grid, i mean `.col-xx-x` inside `.col-xx-x` you should wrap the second level with `.row` class.
2- Remove `display: flex;` from `.white-smoke` div to not affect on the grid.
3- `.intro-boxes` properties override on the first div which has the bug. So you should specify them like this `.intro-boxes.apple p, .intro-boxes.chateau-green p`

Comment: Also the font-awesome include was wrong. I just added the right link